# Turning on Battery health mode

Tags: battery

I have a lenovo Ideapad 310 laptop. Recently I read about Lenovo's battery health mode which drops the charging threshold to 50%. How can I turn it un in ubuntu 20.10? Thanks for help :)

Comment: Do read this page: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/48534

Comment: You're welcome :)